Cut a complex model into equal squares
there is a character model, I thought to cut it into equal squares for 3d printing, when trying to cut the model with a Boolean operation (intersection), the model disappears, apparently there are holes or other problems with polegons or vertices, there is no way to find these flaws, very dense grid, are there any other ways to cut the model?

Correction: The model of clothes and hairstyle were not taken into account, I forgot to hide them, only the model of the girl can be distinguished

open the model in windows 3d builder. It should give you a 'fix it?' pop up if the mesh is non manifold and it will merge it into 1 manifold shell.
But if the clothes and/or hair are 2d planes and have no thickness this is not going to solve that. The model is not made for 3d printing and would require a lot more work to make it ready for it.
If you want to simplify the model you can use a Decimate modifier and lower the ratio, then apply it
